# AngularJs / Ng-Show with a result

Tags: angularjs, numbers, show

I'm a french starter with AngularJS and I have a problem with this code:

```
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 20" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] > 20">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie «Sous-poids» Attention, cette valeur n’est pas avantageuse pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons d’augmenter votre poids jusqu’au atteindre un IMC normal.</span></p>
</div>
<!-- Normalité -->
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 22" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 20">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie de la «Normalité» proche de la limite inférieure. Faites attention parce que une légère perte du poids peut vous amener vers la catégorie «Sous-poids».</span></p>
</div>
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 23" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 22">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Félicitations, votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie de la «Normalité». Pour se maintenir  dans cet état il est très important de continuer à manger de façon équilibrée et de faire de l’activité physique.</span></p>
</div>
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 25" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 23">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie de la «normalité» proche de la limite supérieure. Faites attention parce qu’un léger incrément de poids peut vous amener vers la catégorie de «Surpoids».</span></p>
</div>
<!-- Surcharge pondérale -->
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 30" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 25">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Vous êtes dans la catégorie de «surcharge pondérale», le surpoids peut augmenter la probabilité de contracter des maladies cardiovasculaires comme le diabète, l’hypertension etc. qui représentent des risques pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons de revoir votre alimentation ainsi que votre niveau d’activité physique.</span></p>
</div>
<!-- Surcharge pondérale -->
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 45" ng-hide="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 30">
    <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span ng-model="user.imc">{{ (user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] | number:2 }}</span></p>
    <p><span>Vous êtes dans la catégorie de «surcharge pondérale», l’obésité peut augmenter la probabilité de contracter des maladies cardiovasculaires comme le diabète, l’hypertension etc. qui représentent des risques pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons de revoir votre alimentation ainsi que votre niveau d’activité physique.</span></p>
</div>
```

It's a simple IMC(that is, body mass index) calculator.

Angular shows a message after the user inputs some values in the given fields, with the result. But it shows all messages at the same time; I want it to show them one at a time.

Comment: why you use both ng-show and ng-hide?

Comment: I want to show a message between two numbers following the result of calculated. You have another practice ?

Comment: I will show a message if the result is between 0 and 20 and show an other message between 20 and 30 but to hide the first message ect..

Comment: angular us the seconed one in our case ng-show doesn't effect. i would suggest you to do function that return true false. and only one ng-show or hide

Comment: I can not do grrr .. The messages remain and do not disappear

Comment: You are polluting the HTML markup with code. Instead, use HTML only for markup, and use controllers for code. The entire code you have written can be condensed into one function and one line with `ng-if` or `ng-switch`.

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean by "shows all message in a some value.. not the corresponding time or sometimes while time.."

Comment: You need to learn about controllers and templates in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

the ng-show and ng-hide are the same you dont need to use them both
if its true ng-show show the div and if its true ng-hide the div so in your case ng-hide effect the code 
and also remove the ng-model from the span

you can try something like that

```
<div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="checkBetween(firstnum,secondnum)"> //send number here firstnum will be 10 for example
        <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span>{{user.xnum}}</span></p>
        <p><span>Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie «Sous-poids» Attention, cette valeur n’est pas avantageuse pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons d’augmenter votre poids jusqu’au atteindre un IMC normal.</span></p>
    </div>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.checkBetween = function (firstnum, secondnum) {
        var user = $scope.user;
        var n = user.taille / 100 *2;
        $scope.user.xnum = (user.poids) / n;

        if ($scope.user.xnum > firstnum && $scope.user.xnum < secondnum)
            return true

        return false
    }
```

Comment: Well, they are the same if the content is the same. If the contents are different, it's perfectly appropriate to use both of them(Just saying).

Comment: would like to see an example to use both at the same element and why not to use only one

Comment: If for example you hide 'a' and show 'b'(i.e. replacement), then you need both in a single element. If, for another example, you might hide some value and add a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`.

Comment: I still have the problem. Here is the overall project to better understand. [project](http://duplex38.com/promper/)

Comment: @cst1992 but the have different spans. i ment why would someone pot ng-hide and g-show in the same span div like <div ng-hide="" ng-show="">

Comment: @Erez That's what I'm saying. The element is same(`td`), but the contents are different(One String, Two String).

Comment: @Erez the plunker has all the code. Also what if you want to hide if greater than 80 but show if either less than 70 or greater than 150? The values are sample blood glucose in a patient's blood, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111502/discussion-between-cst1992-and-erez).

Comment: @Erez The OP has no controller defined. If you check source, you'll only see the checkBetween function in the main HTML. http://i.imgur.com/xmnT13m.png

Answer (score 0):

I test your solution but the imc does not appear. I have a very little experience with AngularJS .. :/ Sorry

```
<div ng-controller="checkBetween">  
        <div class="imc-responce sous-poids" ng-show="checkBetween(firstnum,secondnum)"> //send number here firstnum will be 10 for example
            <p>Votre I.M.C est de <span>{{user.xnum}}</span></p>
            <p><span>Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie «Sous-poids» Attention, cette valeur n’est pas avantageuse pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons d’augmenter votre poids jusqu’au atteindre un IMC normal.</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>

        $scope.checkBetween = function (firstnum, secondnum) {
        var user = $scope.user;
        var n = user.taille / 100 *2;
        $scope.user.xnum = (user.poids) / n;

        if ($scope.user.xnum > firstnum && $scope.user.xnum < secondnum)
            return true

        return false
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: you define angular? you have angular app?

Comment: <body ng-app=""> not App

Comment: <body ng-app="myApp">

Comment: try jsfiddle or plunkr where you define jquery and angular

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  If you have additional information to include in the question, edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience, but really this is the concept.

**We have two inputs :**
- input : weight
- input: size

**We calculate the imc :** 
- weight / size² = Imc

**We must display a message with the result:**
Example :

- Imc <= 20 else show  « Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie «Sous-poids» Attention, cette valeur n’est pas avantageuse pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons d’augmenter votre poids jusqu’au atteindre un IMC normal. »
- Imc between 20 and 50 else show « Vous êtes dans la catégorie de «surcharge pondérale», l’obésité peut augmenter la probabilité de contracter des maladies cardiovasculaires comme le diabète, l’hypertension etc. qui représentent des risques pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons de revoir votre alimentation ainsi que votre niveau d’activité physique. »

…

…

Comment: And Show an image (schema). That's why the technique ng-show liked

Comment: Yeah, know what BMI is. Problem is, you don't know enough of Angular to be writing code you're writing. I suggest you attempt more tutorials/read a book that teaches the basics(templates/controllers/directives), and then come back.

Comment: You don't get it. You need a rewrite of the code, or debugging it is going to be hard. Besides, not knowing full Angular,  you won't be able to tell if some code should work or not.

Comment: Besides, if you want the whole code written, you could always go to Freelancer or Upwork :)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  If you have additional information to include in the question, edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're having is a simple typographical error: you're using square brackets which should be parentheses:

`ng-show="(user.poids) / [(user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)] < 22">`

If that were `(user.poids) / ((user.taille/100) * (user.taille/100)) < 22` instead, then your show/hide would work.

That said, there is lots of other room for improvement here:

- It's not necessary (or a good idea) to use both ng-show and ng-hide on the same element.
- You may want to consider calculating the BMI inside a controller or directive, which would make the template much easier to read and to reason about.  (Or, indeed, set the description string on the data model instead of putting it inside separate show/hide divs.)
- I'm not sure what you intend by putting `ng-model` on a `<span>` inside each of the blocks, but it's probably not doing whatever you expect it to.

Here is a quick-and-dirty demonstration:

```js
window.app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  // Note that a shared controller is NOT the best place to stash 
  // the user variable; this is just for demonstration purposes
  $scope.updateIMC = function() {
    $scope.user.imc = ($scope.user.poids / (($scope.user.taille / 100) * ($scope.user.taille / 100))) || 0;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Poids: <input type="text" ng-model="user.poids" ng-change="updateIMC()"><br>
  Taille: <input type="text" ng-model="user.taille" ng-change="updateIMC()"><br>
<p>Votre I.M.C est de {{user.imc}}</p>

<p ng-show="user.imc < 20">Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie «Sous-poids» Attention, cette valeur n’est pas avantageuse pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons d’augmenter votre poids jusqu’au atteindre un IMC normal.</p>
<p ng-show="user.imc >= 20 && user.imc < 23">Félicitations, votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie de la «Normalité». Pour se maintenir  dans cet état il est très important de continuer à manger de façon équilibrée et de faire de l’activité physique.</p>
<p ng-show="user.imc >= 23 && user.imc < 25">Votre poids se trouve dans la catégorie de la «normalité» proche de la limite supérieure. Faites attention parce qu’un léger incrément de poids peut vous amener vers la catégorie de «Surpoids».</p>
<p ng-show="user.imc >= 25 && user.imc < 30">Vous êtes dans la catégorie de «surcharge pondérale», le surpoids peut augmenter la probabilité de contracter des maladies cardiovasculaires comme le diabète, l’hypertension etc. qui représentent des risques pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons de revoir votre alimentation ainsi que votre niveau d’activité physique.</p>
<p ng-show="user.imc >= 30">Vous êtes dans la catégorie de «surcharge pondérale», l’obésité peut augmenter la probabilité de contracter des maladies cardiovasculaires comme le diabète, l’hypertension etc. qui représentent des risques pour votre santé. Nous vous conseillons de revoir votre alimentation ainsi que votre niveau d’activité physique.</p>
```